# Why is this recursively-defined permutation $\sigma:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ symmetrical in the sense that $\sigma(\sigma(n))=n\ $?

Tags: permutations, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, integers

Define a permutation $\sigma:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ recursively by the following rule:

$\sigma(1)=1$ and $\sigma(n)$ is the least $x\ $ in $\ \mathbb{N}\setminus\{\sigma(k): k\leq n-1\}$ such that $x - \sigma(n') \neq n-n'\quad \forall n'\leq n-1.$

If we have two columns of $\mathbb{N}$ in order where the rows are equally spaced, then $\sigma:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ are the arrows from the left column to the right column. We already have arrows from $k$ to $\sigma(k)$ for every $k\leq n-1.$ $\sigma(n)$ is chosen to be the least integer from the remaining range with the condition that the gradient of the arrow from $n$ to $\sigma(n)$ is not the same gradient of any of the arrows before it.

It is clear that $\sigma$ is an injection. I decided to investigate $\sigma$ by writing down the first few terms of $\sigma(n)$ and using arrows to represent the function $\sigma.$

The first few terms are:

$\sigma(1) = 1,\ \sigma(2) = 3,\ \sigma(3) = 2,\ \sigma(4) = 6,\ \sigma(5) = 8,\ \sigma(6) = 4,\ \sigma(7) = 11,\ \sigma(8) = 5,\ \sigma(9) = 14,\ldots $.

Using my arrow diagram, it was not difficult to see that $\sigma$ is surjective also. But I also noticed that there was a symmetry of reflection in my diagram, and this surprised me, because I couldn't think of a good reason for this symmetry. In mathematical terms, it seems that $\sigma(\sigma(n))=n.$

My question is:

> Is it true that $\sigma(\sigma(n))=n$ for all $n,$ and why is this/ how can this
> be proven?

Comment: See [A019444](http://oeis.org/A019444)

Comment: @lulu thanks. It says in the comments, " 
Self-inverse when considered as a permutation or function, i.e., a(a(n)) = n. - Howard A. Landman, Sep 25 2001". However, I don't know where to look for this proof. Can you advise please?

Comment: [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL12/Venkatachala/venkatachala2.html) is a link from that page.  It purports to include a proof, though I did not check it.

Comment: @lulu thanks. Yeah the proof is about a page and a half long, so is non-trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, a full proof is given [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL12/Venkatachala/venkatachala2.pdf) (**proof of (b)**) on pages $8$ and $9$.